# Incomplete http response using apache HttpEntity

Tags: android, json, apache, httpresponse

I am maintaining an Android app that was working quite well, but that all of a sudden started presenting a strange behavior where one specific httpRequest(that has a big Json response) started to return an incomplete response.

That Json response just could not be parsed as it ended abruptly  with "...".

I checked using Postman, that my response was complete. Also, the iOS version of this app, was still working using the same request.

I am using `org.apache.http.HttpEntity`.

Here is my code:

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream content = entity.getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
String line;

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    builder.append(line);
}

responseString = builder.toString();
```

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If your JSON ends with "..." so the server side is generating a response ending with "...". I suggest you ckeck your backend, maybe some request parameter or http header appended by Android API makes server generates a response like this.

Comment: That thing is that nothing changed in the backend structure... everything was exactly as it was before. But the request just stopped working just on the Android platform.